# In Chrome Dev Tools Timeline: What are the gray bars surrounding resource downloads in the network row?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following view in Chrome dev tools:

[image: timeline network view]

What do the gray bars mean surrounding the purple CSS requests? I assume the portion before the request is queing time, but what about after? Is this time spent parsing the CSS or is it blocking waiting for something else? How can I determine this in more detail?

If it helps, I have included the "Main" portion of the timeline: [image: Chrome main timeline]

And the CPU profile here:

[image]

From those views I can see "Parse HTML" and "Evaluate/Compile Script". Does this mean the page is blocking on that script evaluation or could that include CSS parsing? I see "Parse Stylesheet" later on so I am thinking the gray bars indicate blocking without activity on the CSS once it is downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the gray bars?

Comment: Yes you can see the resulting tooltip in my screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correlate the gray bars with idle times related to script evaluation when my HTML loaded. So, essentially, this is time that is blocking waiting for HTML evaluation to complete. In particular, I had LastPass enabled and it was running an evaluation on my HTML. Below, I have included a diagram:

[image]

Once I turned the extension off, this idle time went away.